# Trying to rename python virtualenv, opencv errors

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv, rename

Have been happily working on a hobby project incorporating python in a virtual environment using opencv.

Today for admin reasons I needed to change the name of the virtual env.  Have done so before with other projects without issue using virtualenvwrapper:

```
cpvirtualenv oldenv newenv
rmvirtualenv oldenv
```

So basically exact same but renamed copy with same pip installs, opencv files etc.  However now when I run the python script in the newenv I get:

```
(opencv)[1]dan@dual-lt ~/PyProjects/facedetect $ python facedetectlive.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "facedetectlive.py", line 10, in <module>
import cv
File "/home/dan/PyProjects/.virtualenvs/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py", line 1, in <module>
from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If i test cv from python shell it confirms something is not right:

```
(opencv)[1]dan@dual-lt ~/PyProjects/facedetect $ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 17 2013, 15:31:50) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dan/PyProjects/.virtualenvs/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>> import numpy
>>> import scipy
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The strange thing is if i restore the oldenv so newenv and oldenv are side-by-side in .virtualenvs then the above all works even though I am working in the newenv.

So for my newenv works depends on oldenv still being there.  I dont understand why as I can confirm newenv is a carbon copy of oldenv in terms of files and structure including cv.py etc.

Have persisted all day and I'm none the wiser.  If anyone can be so kind as to put me right I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because of the shared libraries being loaded when you do `import cv`. Shared libraries are located by using the [rpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) and presumably the `cpvirtualenv` doesn't change the rpath of the libraries installed.

When you have them side-by-side, the original libraries are now locate-able and the import succeeds.

One solution is to do a `pip freeeze` to get a `requirements.txt` from your old environment and use that to get all the packages in your new environment.

Comment: @vikramis, thanks but `pip freeze --local` produces same results for both oldenv & newenv, namely Pillow, scipy & numpy.

Comment: Yes it will since you copied the environment. I am saying that the copy didn't change the rpath's in the .so files in the environment. I was merely suggesting a replacement for the `cpvirtualenv`.

Comment: Thanks vikramls.  Used sublimetext to do a search for 'oldenv' within all files across the newenv directory.  This returned some oldenv results in newenv/bin which I manually edited.  Also copied over all .so files to newenv/lib.  I guess `cpvirtualenv` is not always a comprehensive solution for renaming virtualenvs.